# Static Property Lazy Load Regex Compile option

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I have the following class and property:

```
public static class Util
{
   private static Regex _regexTest;

   private static Regex RegexTest => _regexTest ?? (_regexTest = new Regex(@"^\+?\d{0,2}", RegexOptions.Compiled));

   public static bool ValidateNumber(string numberAsString)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberAsString))
            return false;

       return RegexTest.Match(numberAsString).Success;
   }
 }
```

Will this lazy load the compiling of the Regex expression if the consumer only passes empty/null values to the ValidateNumber method? Or because of this is static, will it still compile it?

Answer (score 1):

The Regex is only constructed when `numberAsString` is non-empty the first time during runtime. At that point, it would be compiled and possibly cached. Otherwise, `_regexTest` would remain null. [More details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions):

> If a Regex object is **constructed** with the RegexOptions.Compiled
> option, it compiles the regular expression to explicit MSIL code
> instead of high-level regular expression internal instructions.

In other words, the `Regex.Compiled` option causes runtime compilation, rather than what we might guess to be build-time compilation.

Answer (score 1):

We can check the action of the code as follows.

Create an additional class with the method:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Regex was created");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Change `Util` class like this:

```
private static Regex RegexTest => _regexTest ?? (_regexTest = new Regex(@"^\+?\d{0,2}" + Helper.Test(), RegexOptions.Compiled));
```

Let's do a test.

```
Console.WriteLine(Util.ValidateNumber(null));
```

Output:

```
false
```

Test 2:

```
Console.WriteLine(Util.ValidateNumber("1"));
```

Output:

```
Regex was created
true
```

As you can see, in the first case the code is not called.

Comment: Nice simple test!